# Output of Cout function in C++

Tags: c++, output, cout

The statement `cout<< 0 || 1` gives output 0. Shouldn't the output be 1 since the statement `0 || 1` evaluates to true?

Comment: cout << (0||1);

Comment: you have to put the expression inside parenthesis.

Comment: I sometimes wish we could close duplicate with a link to cppreference... See [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `operator <<` has higher precedence than `operator ||`.

Comment: thanks..I got the answer

Comment: that `auto test = std::cout << 0 || 1;` works shows what happens.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've found a duplicate that I think is sufficiently close. There may even be one for logical operators in cout, but we don't need one for every possible combination anyway.

Comment: @cigien Nice one!